# Testing url redirect with jest, enzyme and react router

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I have an issue I cant find any solution on github's projects

I am trying to test conditional (with props) redirection using react router as context, but can't succeed because the rendered instance is null. Here's the error message:

```
ShallowWrapper::context() can only be called on wrapped nodes that have a non-null instance
```

Here's my component:

```
import Router from "next/router";

export default (privateArea = props => {
  if (props.auth.isSignedIn === "SUCCESS") {
    Router.push("/");
  }
  return <p>You are in the private area</p>;
});
```

Here's my test:

```
import privateArea from "./private";
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

import { Router } from "next/router";
jest.mock("next/router");

describe("Redirect Test Suite", () => {
  let container, props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);
    props = {
      auth: jest.fn(() => {})
    };
    const context = { router: new Router() };
    container = shallow(<privateArea {...props} />, { context });
  });

  it("renders without crashing", () => {
    expect(container).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("redirects when not Signed In", () => {
    container.setProps({ auth: { isSignedIn: "FAIL" } });
    expect(container.context("router")).toBeCalled();
  });

  it("renders when Signed In", () => {
    container.setProps({ auth: { isSignedIn: "SUCCESS" } });
    expect(container.context("router")).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help/hints

Best